# How to terminate a process in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

How can I terminate process using vbscript. PLEASE NOTE, I need to terminate process that runs under windows 64-bit environment as native 64 (not using select * from win_32_Process)

Thanks,

Comment: WIN32_Process returns both 64 and 32-bit processes!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The [`Win32_Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372.aspx) class provides access to both 32-bit and 64-bit processes when the script is run from a 64-bit command shell.

If this is not an option for you, you can try using the [`taskkill`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx) command:

```
Dim oShell : Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Launch notepad '
oShell.Run "notepad"
WScript.Sleep 3000

' Kill notepad '
oShell.Run "taskkill /im notepad.exe", , True
```

Answer (score 3):

Just type in the following command: taskkill /f /im (program name)
To find out the im of your program open task manager and look at the process while your program is running. After the program has run a process will disappear from the task manager; that is your program.

Answer (score 2):

I know I am late to the game LOL, but this is what I did to kill SmartScreen.

1. Create text file KillSmartScreen.vbs
2. Edit with Notepad:

   ```vb
   Dim oShell : Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

   'Kill smartscreen.exe  aka Windows Defender SmartScreen 

   oShell.Run "taskkill /f /im smartscreen.exe"
   ```
3. Double click KillSmartScreen.vbs to run.

Works like a champ.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the code to exit from the loop:**

```
Function main()
do while (SOME_CONDITION)
    If SOMETHING_1 = 1 Then
        DO_SOMETHIONG()
        Exit Do
    End If
loop
End Function

main()
```